# Incorrect Number of Bindings on SQL Query using Panda Read SQL

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite

I am getting the following error

> Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 0 supplied.

Here is the Python code that uses pandas and bindings that's throwing the error:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd


def get_van_data_comp(companyname):
  con = sqlite3.connect(str(DBFILE))
  van = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT NAME as 'BRANCH NAME', CHASSIS, DAYSINSTOCK, DESCRIPTION FROM VAN INNER JOIN BRANCH ON VAN.BRANCHID = BRANCH.ID WHERE NAME=?" , con,(companyname,))
  print(van)
  return van
```

Comment: Because you're using positional arguments. The statement expects named arguments if you're not passing all of them. It thinks you're passing a value for `index_col` based on position. You need `params = (companyname,)`. See [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html)

Comment: yep, thanks just figured it out haha!